# Need to recover soft deleted mailboxes on 2010 exchange server after 2013 migration failed

Tags: exchange, migration, mailbox, datastore

The situation I am facing is that we were in the middle of moving mailboxes from an exchange 2010 sp3 environment over to a server running exchange 2013 and the exchange 2013 server had a raid error and we lost all data on the 2013 box immediately after the migration (completely dead array, all VM's gone of course :)

I am able to see the mailboxes in "soft deleted" state on the 2010 Exchange box, I have tried running microsoft's recommended command to restore the soft deleted mailboxes the command errors out indicating that user's mailbox is on the 2013 server. Unsure how to proceed and would love any pointers anyone may have.

Comment: Restore from backups.  You *did* take backups before you did this, right?

Comment: We actually tried that, the problem was that the old mailbox datastore and the recipient configurations did not want to talk after the restore as the mailbox properties were changed somewhere in the AD schema during the 2010-2013 mailbox move. Very fugly.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using Kernel for Exchange server from Nucleus Technologies to export all the soft deleted mailboxes out to PST. Given the time constraints we had to get mail flowing it was decided to hurry up a scheduled google apps migration.

While I was less than impressed with Google's import tools all in all the switch went well. Not exactly a pretty scenario but all is well in the end.

Comment: Best option to restore from backup. Or Try Ontrack, Stellar Exchange Recovery!!